# pause all threads without wait

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, thread-safety

I am trying to build a bot with selenium. the problem is that from time to time the website logging me out without any notice. I know how to detect it, and I know the way to handle it. the problem is that it is not reasonable to check before every line if the server logged me out. this is what I can do:

```
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(url);
    Connect(driver, loginData);
    if(isConnected(driver) == false)
        reconnect(driver, loginData);
    driver.findElement(By.id("element-id")).click();
    if(isConnected(driver) == false)
        reconnect(driver, loginData);
    ...
```

But checking if I need to reconnect every line is not a good solution.
I thought about making a thread that checks all the time if I disconnected but I don't know how to pause the main thread until I reconnect to the server when I find out I disconnected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a solution similar to your own, but instead of creating your own wrapper to `ChromeDriver`, you can use `EventFiringWebDriver` for that.

Answer (score 1):

you can run the check inside a while loop in a side thread, and if the server disconnects you, stop the main thread. after you reconnect, restart it again.

Comment: that is exactly what I want but I don't know how to stop the main thread from the side thread when a disconnection has detected

Comment: ah ok. seems like i misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

The website logging you out seems to be time out. As I guess, you are testing in a non-production environment, please look for how to set the time_out = 0 (no-expire).

Thread solutions would be too clumsy and a single non synchronous miss can produce undetectable erroneous results.

Comment: it's not a timeout problem. some of the disconnections are due to time out but some are from another user logs in to the same account.

Comment: In that case, if you login again from your thread, the user will be forefully logged out of the system. It may fall into a cycle. Talk with the developer on how to allow multiple logins for the same user on local deployment

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by wrapping `ChromeDriver` with a class of my own that checks before every operation if a disconnect has detected. if anyone has a better solution I would like to hear. This is my solution:

```
    public java.util.List<WebElement> findElements(By by) throws disconnectException {
    if(keepLogin) {
        if(checkConnectionOver()) {
            throw new disconnectException();
        }
    }
    return driver.findElements(by);
}

public WebElement findElement(By by) throws disconnectException {
    if(keepLogin) {
        if(checkConnectionOver()) {
            throw new disconnectException();
        }
    }
    return driver.findElement(by);
}

public Object executeScript(String script, Object... args) throws disconnectException {
    if(keepLogin) {
        if(checkConnectionOver()) {
            throw new disconnectException();
        }
    }
    return driver.executeScript(script, args);
}

public void get(String url) {
    driver.get(url);
}

public String getCurrentUrl() {
    return driver.getCurrentUrl();
}
```